# How to get rid of last comma in javascript?

Tags: javascript

When it Prints all the days along with the comma so at the end there is one more and extra comma after Sunday comes.could you help me out?

```
<script>
    var days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
                'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    for (var i=0; i<days.length; i++) {
    document.write(days[i] + ', ');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Just don't print a comma when "i" is equal to `days.length - 1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) :

```
document.write(days.join(', '));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `days.join(', ');` instead of an iteration through your array.

**EDIT :**

Further more, you can do it in one line : 

`document.write(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'].join(', '));`

Answer (score 1):

simple logic is to print it like this

```
var days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
            'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
document.write(days[0]);
for (var i=1; i < (days.length); i++) {
    document.write(',' + days[i]);
}
```

or

```
var days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',
            'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
for (var i=0; i < (days.length-1); i++) {
    document.write(days[i] + ',');
}
document.write(days[days.length-1]);
```